# How to use expresser for python on windows

Tags: python-2.7, scripting, automation, build-automation, ui-automation

How to use **Xpresser** for **python 2.7**  in **windows** for **image based GUI automation** , i don't want to use sikuli ..as it takes to much time to run without ide , **are there other opensource option for this purpose** . For my Purpose the script is required to run continuously based on some condition .

Comment: dont you mean Xpresser ? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xpresser

Answer (score 3):

Not directly an answer to how to make Xpresser work on Windows, but here are some alternatives:

- [pyautogui locate functions](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions). It is a mature library, well worth a look.
- [sikulpy](https://github.com/shish/sikulpy) which is an overlay above pyautogui, specialized in providing a similar experience to Sikuli, but with a codebase in pure Python (instead of Java for Sikuli).
- [lackey](https://github.com/glitchassassin/lackey), similar to sikulpy.
- [eirikb's linux shell solution](https://gist.github.com/eirikb/c189a7d8406b2897dad0e86086be1b23).